# Adding table on another table so that they continue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 10 rows, and I want to add three more tables to these 10 rows so that they continue one after the other. The next table starts with 11 and the third of the 21st.

This is the DataFrame

```
Date    Open    High    Low     Close   Adj Close   Volume
0   2019-01-17  346.209991  351.500000  344.149994  347.309998     347.309998   3676700
1   2019-01-18  323.000000  327.130005  299.730011  302.260010  302.260010  24150800
2   2019-01-22  304.820007  308.000000  295.500000  298.920013  298.920013  12066700
3   2019-01-23  292.500000  294.500000  281.690002  287.589996  287.589996  12530000
4   2019-01-24  283.029999  293.679993  279.279999  291.510010  291.510010  8012200
5   2019-01-25  294.390015  298.519989  289.549988  297.040009  297.040009  7249600
6   2019-01-28  292.910004  297.459991  287.750000  296.380005  296.380005  6423300
7   2019-01-29  295.269989  298.559998  291.799988  297.459991  297.459991  4621700
8   2019-01-30  300.450012  309.000000  298.489990  308.769989  308.769989  11250300
9   2019-01-31  301.000000  311.559998  294.000000  307.019989  307.019989  12569200
10  2019-02-01  305.420013  316.100006  303.500000  312.209991  312.209991  7283400
```

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.append`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append

Comment: for example df.append(df2). Ok I got it.Thank you.

Comment: Look at pd. concat too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.append`. From the documentation:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))

combined_df = df1.append(df2)
```

More information:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append